# How to load multiple Json files (which might have different fields) into one hive table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have two JSON files which are being generated on two different days.
Both of them come under the same business specification. So I want to insert into one hive table. How it can be done?

Scenario:

fist JSON:
{
"a":2,
"b":3,
}

Second JSON:
{
"a":1,
"b",2,
"c",3
}

Both of the above has to be inserted into the same hive table. And how to read the fields and create a new table out of them which will be a flat one?

Answer (score 0):

Put your files into the same table location (or use [**LOAD DATA command**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables)) and use [**JSONSerDe**](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (
  a int,
  b int,
  c int
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '<HDFS location>' --this is HDFS/S3 location
;
```

If some JSON object does not contain all keys defined in the table DDL, absent keys will be parsed as NULL.

Comment: Let me put the requirement this way. I receive one JSON file each day and I am not sure about the keys present in the files. But all the JSON coming from the same source. So how to create a flatten table with this JSONs. thanks!

Comment: You should know keys to create a table with columns parsed from JSON. And you shoul know keys to extract them from JSON. You can create table with single string column containing the whole JSON and later use json_tuple or get_json_object to get values, but anyway you need to know what are you extracting from JSON exactly

Comment: @Asrinivas  If you want to create table dynamically with columns unknown then it is not possible in Hive. Extract all possible keys first then create a table. But better create table with only those columns defined which you need right now. Later you can re-create the table with more columns

Comment: I think I am going with the same option. Where I am going to create a table with a current set of attributes and which will have all dates data. When a new attribute will be introduced, I will be altering the table to add this new column.

Comment: @Asrinivas Yeah.Re-creating /Altering table is metadata operation only and you can do it easily later, it does not affect underlying JSON data